# Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, resteasy

I have a `RestEasy` Client which gets the Data from rest endpoint. The test looks like

```
    @Test
    public void testGetAllVariablesWithoutQueryParamPass() throws Exception {
        final ClientRequest clientCreateRequest = new ClientRequest("http://localhost:9090/variables");
        final MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParameters = clientCreateRequest.getFormParameters();
        final String name = "testGetAllVariablesWithoutQueryParamPass";
        formParameters.putSingle("name", name);
        formParameters.putSingle("type", "String");
        formParameters.putSingle("units", "units");
        formParameters.putSingle("description", "description");
        formParameters.putSingle("core", "true");

        final GenericType<List<VariablePresentation>> typeToken = new GenericType<List<VariablePresentation>>() {
        };
        final ClientResponse<List<VariablePresentation>> clientCreateResponse = clientCreateRequest.post(typeToken);
        assertEquals(201, clientCreateResponse.getStatus());
        final List<VariablePresentation> variables = clientCreateResponse.getEntity();
        assertNotNull(variables);
        assertEquals(1, variables.size());

    }
```

I had no idea how to validate `ClientResponse` so I got help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774800/resteasy-how-to-validate-clientresponse-body)
But when I run my Test I see a separate Issue, I am not sure how to resolve this, please help me with this

```
testGetAllVariablesWithoutQueryParamPass(com.myorg.project.market.integration.TestVariable): Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type application/json and type java.util.List<com.myorg.project.service.presentation.VariablePresentation>
```

---

After adding the maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-beta-2</version>
</dependency>
```

Tests in error:

```
testGetAllVariablesWithoutQueryParamPass(com.myorg.project.market.integration.TestVariable): org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token(..)

Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 1
```

There is a follow up question [RestEasy : org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token(..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776034/resteasy-org-codehaus-jackson-map-jsonmappingexception-can-not-deserialize-in)

Comment: Are you using Maven to manage your application? You need a the RESTEasy Jackson provider in your classpath.

Comment: thats great. Please confirm that you have a dependency for `resteasy-jackson-provider`.

Comment: I just added that and now runnning `mvn clean install`

Comment: It failed, I added the **update**

Comment: The same problem as for RESTEasy client: reconstructing an object (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004660/resteasy-client-reconstructing-an-object)

Comment: Hmmm, you get that error if you are trying to deserialize a collection out of a JSON string that is ***not*** an array. Try calling your service in a REST tool and dumping the return JSON (add it to the question as well).

Comment: is there a neat way to get around with this problem?

Comment: I have opened a separate question