# JSON string to Java object in REST API

Tags: java, json, tomcat, servlets

I want to receive statistics of a switch in a virtual created network using Floodlight API and Apache Tomcat web server.I'm receiving following JSON String from the Floodlight API in a localhost:

```
(http://127.0.0.1:8080/wm/core/switch/00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01/queue/json):
```

The reveived JSON data from the localhost is:

```
{
 "00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01":   [

             {
                "portNumber" : 2,

                "queueId" : 0,

                "transmitBytes" : 1944145,

                "transmitPackets" : 1684,

                "transmitErrors" : 0
             }

                              ]

}
```

and I want to add this information in a web browser using REST API in Java running in the Tomcat server. 
"00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01" is the ID of the switch, and the other JSON strings are statistics about the switch.

My main class:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


      // Get data from Floodlight API as a JSON String
    ClientResource cResourceQueues = new     ClientResource("http://127.0.0.1:8080/wm/core/switch/all/queue/json");
    StringWriter sWriterQueues = new StringWriter();

    // get JSON data about switches; the data is put in a string writer
    try {

        cResourceQueues.get(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).write(sWriterQueues);

    } catch (ResourceException e) {
        request.setAttribute("error", "Connection with FLoodLight failed!");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/connectionError.jsp").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }

    // put data from string writer into a string object
    String queueJson = sWriterQueues.toString();

    // map JSON data to Java objects
    // ObjectMapper converts between JSON - Java
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            // Access the "Queue" class
    ArrayList<Queue> queues = mapper.readValue(queueJson, new TypeReference<ArrayList<Queue>>() {
    });

    // put objects in the request so we can use them later in the JSP
    request.setAttribute("queues", queues);

    // redirect to the jsp
    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/showInfo.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

I'm mapping JSON string to Java objects in this "Queue" class:

```
public class Queue {

private String[] portNumber;
private String[] queueId;
private String[] transmitBytes;

private String[] transmitPackets;
private String[] transmitErrors;

public Queue() {
}

public Queue(String[] portNumber, String[] queueId, String[] transmitBytes, String[] transmitPackets) {
    this.portNumber = portNumber;
    this.queueId = queueId;
    this.transmitBytes = transmitBytes;
    this.transmitPackets = transmitPackets;
}

public String[] getportNumber() {
    return portNumber;
}

public void setportNumber(String[] portNumber) {
    this.portNumber = portNumber;
}

public String[] getqueueId() {
    return queueId;
}

public void setqueueId(String[] queueId) {
    this.queueId = queueId;
}

public String[] gettransmitBytes() {
    return transmitBytes;
}

public void settransmitBytes(String[] transmitBytes) {
    this.transmitBytes = transmitBytes;
}

public String[] gettransmitPackets() {
    return transmitPackets;
}

public void settransmitPackets(String[] transmitPackets) {
    this.transmitPackets = transmitPackets;
}

public String[] gettransmitErrors() {
    return transmitErrors;
}

public void setLastSeen(String[] transmitErrors) {
    this.transmitErrors = transmitErrors;
}

}
```

I want to know, whether this "Queue" class is mapping all the JSON Strings (mentioned above) to Java objects, since the ArrayList in my main class returns an error, when I'm running the Tomcat web server.

Comment: I found the issue. According to this link: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776034/resteasy-org-codehaus-jackson-map-jsonmappingexception-can-not-deserialize-in.

It's expecting to parse an array (which would begin with a ('[') but it's encountering the beginning token for an object ('{'). Does someone know how to parse an array from the first '[' to ']' in my JSON data ?